# How to set path for a system call from inside a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, phantomjs

I am trying to execute phantom.js module from rails. So far I've successfully installed the binary and the path for phantomjs seems to be working fine.

However when I try to run it from a rails app using backtick (for example: phantomjs rasterize.js http://google.com 1.jpg), it says No such file or directory.

I think the reason is it can't find the path for rasterize.js 
I tried putting the rasterize.js file in #{Rails.root}, inside public folder, inside controller folder but nothing works.

How can I solve this problem?

====

UPDATE: To clarify, i'm posting which code works inside my controller and which doesn't.

```
def create
  'phantomjs'
end
```

<= Above code doesn't spit out path error, and when I send a request from the browser, phantomjs process *does* get invoked, resulting in opening up the console in the server side.

```
def create
  'phantomjs rasterize.js'
end
```

<= This doesn't work, and it spits out error saying "No such file or directory", and that's why I think it has to do with rails not being able to find rasterize.js's path. I tried putting rasterize.js inside public folder, inside controllers folder, and inside the main directory: #{Rails.root}, but it's always the same.

Comment: There's not so much of a code. It seems like it's clearly path problem, and I did update the question a bit...

Comment: Try to set the path explicitly like `"phantomjs #{Rails.root}/rasterize.js"`

Comment: I'm starting to think it might not be a path problem. I tried setting the absolute path and the command does include the absolute path, but it just says no such file or directory. Maybe rails doesn't allow javascript execution? :(

Comment: sh: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs /Users/e/Projects/rails/screenshots/app/controllers/js/rasterize.js: No such file or directory

Comment: oh by this was after an attempt to place rasterize.js inside a separate folder called js, which I created..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting... I've been trying all kinds of combinations and finally ran into a case that works, and it's not what I expected:

```
%x("/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /Users/e/Dropbox/Projects/rails/screenshots/rasterize.js http://google.com app/assets/images/2709.jpg")
```

<= This doesn't work.

```
system("/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /Users/e/Dropbox/Projects/rails/screenshots/rasterize.js http://google.com app/assets/images/2709.jpg")
```

<= This works.

I thought these all work internally the same, except for return values? Maybe I was wrong?

Comment: Don't use quotes inside `%x(...)`. Also, I notice in the update to your question you put single quotes around the commands instead of backticks. Was that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Let say your command is `cmd`.It is good to know that `%(cmd)` and `exec(cmd)`, change the process you are on so if you are in rails and changed the directory it will exit. On the other hand ``cmd`` and `system(cmd)` will let you continute working.

I learned that from this blog. http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html